# Efficiently swap elements pairwise in a singly linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I have written a function in C++ that works fine to swap elements pairwise in a singly linked list. However, I was wondering if there was more efficient way to do the same. To be specific the function I wrote has a case which deals when there are only two elements in the linked list. I was wondering if this case can be omitted and put in the general case. I tried doing that but failed to get the output. Is it possible? Here is my code snippet...

```
struct Node* swap(struct Node* head){
  struct Node* temp = NULL;
  struct Node* cur;
  struct Node* next;

  cur = head;
  next = cur->next;

  // Empty list.
  if(head == NULL){
    cout<<"List is empty. \n";
    return NULL;
  }

  // Only one element in the list.
  if(next == NULL){
    return cur;
  }

  // If two elements in the list.
  else if(next->next == NULL){
    cur->next = NULL;
    next->next = cur;
    return next;
  }

  // General case.
  else{
    head = next;
    while(cur!=NULL){

      if(next == NULL)
        break;

      if(next->next == NULL)
        break;      

      cur->next = next->next;
      next->next = cur;


      if(temp == NULL)
        temp = cur;

      else{
        temp->next = next;
        temp = cur;
       }    

       cur = cur->next;
       next = cur->next;


     }
    return head;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can encompass the two-element case, the one-element case and the zero-element case in the general case. The loop can begin with

```
while(cur != NULL && cur->next != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless i'm missing something, it seems Beta's solution should do it.

Also, not an answer but bother me:

```
if(temp == NULL){
    temp = cur;
}
else{
    temp->next = next;
    temp = cur;
}
```

If temp ends up as cur anyway you can compress this into

```
if(temp != NULL){
    temp->next = next;
}
temp = cur;
```